# Protocol number for socket creation for UDP protocol

Tags: c, sockets

I am in the process of making a socket for a client in C. I would like to use the UDP protocol, but I can't seem to find it in the man pages.

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

Comment: [`man socket`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html): `PF_INET`, `PF_UNIX`.

Comment: @tadman they only give the domain protocol number but not the UDP protocol number I just don't know which number to put for the last argument of a socket function

Comment: @tadman could you tell me how you found this on the man page that you sent me because I'm just lost in c

Comment: For UDP over IP: `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`. If you're learning this in C I found [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_Network_Programming) invaluable.

Comment: @tadman i'll make sure to read it thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`man 2 socket`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) manual page only describes the general usage of the `socket()` system call. It does not go into much detail about each possible protocol. For that, there are several different manual pages under section `7`.

For the IP protocol, you can check [`man 7 ip`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), which states:

```
An IP socket is created using socket(2):

    socket(AF_INET, socket_type, protocol);

Valid socket types include SOCK_STREAM to open a stream socket,
SOCK_DGRAM to open a datagram socket, and SOCK_RAW to open a
raw(7) socket to access the IP protocol directly.

protocol is the IP protocol in the IP header to be received or
sent.  Valid values for protocol include:

   - 0 and IPPROTO_TCP for tcp(7) stream sockets;
   - 0 and IPPROTO_UDP for udp(7) datagram sockets;
   - IPPROTO_SCTP for sctp(7) stream sockets; and
   - IPPROTO_UDPLITE for udplite(7) datagram sockets.
```

So for an UDP socket you want:

```c
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

Or equivalently:

```c
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```